# Do cursed investigators in the herald variant repeatedly fall unconscious?

Tags: arkham-horror, arkham-horror-curse-of-dark-pharaoh

In the Herald variant of Curse of the Dark Pharaoh, cursed investigators lose stamina every upkeep. If they reach zero and become unconscious, do they wake at St. Mary's Hospital only to keep falling unconscious unless someone sends a blessing their way? Do they lose the curse when becoming unconscious? I didn't see any reference to losing or retaining blessed/cursed status but surely there is some means to keep investigators from being caught in this loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since an investigator gets to roll to see if they lose a Cursed or Blessed status on the upkeep after losing their stamina, they won't get stuck in an infinite loop.  If a person is worried about not being able to do anything because of their curse, they can use their Encounter at St. Mary's to simply heal one.  Their health will go from 1 to 2, then back to 1 next round.  At least with that, the person can make one move and go somewhere to do SOMETHING, rather then being bed-ridden.  There are ways around it, but I guess the solution really would be "don't get cursed".

Comment: So once the investigator has 1 stamina at the start of an upkeep, they really have no way to make any moves until that 1 is rolled to release the curse as they repeatedly lose and regain 1 stamina. That, or, more dependably with such a small sample of rolls, someone else either sends a blessing their way or goes to St. Mary's Hospital to explicitly heal them. Do I have that right?

Comment: Look my answer over again.  I changed it a bit to show a solution to the problem.

Comment: Thanks. Your original answer made me realize that, but your edit does make it even more evident.